# Change default sdk version of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I installed android studio few minutes ago and it opens, but when I try to build apk or run project I get no resource found that matches the given name "android:TextAppearance.Widget.Material.Button.Inverse in values 23 ...

Everything was working before I formatted my laptop but this error is showing and I don't want to download API 23, I want to use 21. This happened for me before and when I uninstalled android studio then installed it after few days no error appeared!

I tried to change project structure stuff but the values-23 is found in the project and can't be deleted so am stuck. Now I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the error appears in design view try changing the api like this :

[image]

If this doesn't help, can you post some of your build.gradle file..the android part were compiled sdks is listed and all the compile support libraries

Comment: no am saying i have values 23 folder that cant be edited !

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, you can change your Android SDK location under File | Project Structure | SDK Location

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

Answer (score -1):

In build.gradle file, modify compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion appropriately to have the app build for you.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```